# View page return null pointer exception

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller

when im trying to access the signUp, as i see in the debug, there is a problem when the code get to the view. 
im getting run time exception "System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null."
Please HELP

here is the full failure :

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.

happen here :

```
  @{
      ViewBag.Title = "SignUp";
   }
```

SignUp.cshtml

```
  <body>
<div class="signup-form">
    <form class="signup-form" action="SignupSubmit">
        <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
            <h2>SignUp</h2>
            <h3>Create an account</h3>
            <h4 class="mb-3">Please complete your details : </h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="firstName">Id number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userid" id="idnum" value="@Model.userid"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.userid)
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Valid id number is required.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="@Model.firstName"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.firstName)
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Valid first name is required.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="@Model.lastName"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.lastName)
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Valid last name is required.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email </label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="you@example.com" value="@Model.email">  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.email)
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" value="@Model.password"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.password)
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please enter a valid password with numbers and letters.
                </div>
            </div>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" required="required"> I accept the <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> &amp; <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></label>
            <hr class="mb-4">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Already have an account? Login here. ", "SignIn", "User", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

UserController.cs

```
    public ActionResult SignUp()
    {
        return View(new User());
    }
    public ActionResult SignupSubmit(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AddUserToDB(user);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("SignUp");
        }

        TempData["Falied"] = "You can now connect with your details";
        return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "User");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public bool AddUserToDB(User u)
    {
        try
        {
            UserDal dal = new UserDal();
            dal.users.Add(u);
            dal.SaveChanges();
        }

        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            foreach (var errors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in errors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    // get an error message 
                    string errorMessage = validationError.ErrorMessage;
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                    validationError.PropertyName,
                    validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

User.cs

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{9}$", ErrorMessage = "ID must be with 9 numbers")]
    public string userid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-z]+$", ErrorMessage = "First Name must be only Characters")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Last Name must be only Characters")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$", ErrorMessage = "Email must conatain characters seperate with @")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Email must be with at least 4 characters or Maximum 50 caracters")]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$", ErrorMessage = "Password must conatain eight characters, at least one letter and one number")]
    [StringLength(8, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be with 8 Characters")]
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string permission { get; set; }
    public float totalHoures { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Add (@model User)  before the line that throws the error

Comment: @model MyStoreProject.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SignUp";
} there is already @...

Comment: Why do you even want to show value="Model.Firstname" at signUp?:.  Just remove (new user) in the return view and there is no need to set values when a user is signing up

Comment: the issue was that user was not sending here ...         else
        {
            return View("SignUp");
        }.. so i changed this return to "t=return View("SignUp",user);

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that user was not sending here ...

```
else { 
        return View("SignUp");
      }
```

so i changed the code to

```
return View("SignUp",user);
```

and now it working as expected.
my view is strongly typed view, and i just want to see the errors messages next the text box which are not passed the validation successfully.